# How to access a same cursor in multiple goroutines from mongo-driver go package

Tags: mongodb, go, collections, sdk, cursor

I am using multiple goroutines to read documents from cursor in MongoDB golang sdk. But its not returning all documents. **Note**: Its working correctly with single goroutine.

I want to read all documents from same collection cursor from multiple goroutines

Sample code:

```
cursor, err := coll.Find(context.TODO(), filter, opts)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Finding all documents ERROR:", err)
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)

    // If the API call was a success
} else {

    // iterate over docs using Next()
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
     ...............
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple goroutines calling `cursor.Next`, then the cursor will be advancing in all of the goroutinges, when *any* of the goroutines calls `cursor.Next`.  What you'd probably want to do is have a single goroutine for reading, but then you could pass the results to a channel, and then you could *process* each document in a separate goroutine.  Something like:

```
dataChannel := make(chan mongoResult)

func handleMongoResults() {
    for {
        res := <-dataChannel
        // do something
    }
}

go handleMongoResults()
go handleMongoResults()


for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    var result mongoResult
    if err := cursor.Decode(&result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    dataChannel <- result
}
```

And then obviously make sure you exit your goroutines when you are done processing results.

Comment: Thanks !!!. But if I use cursor.All() is taking 98% of total time. And if I run different collections on different goroutines, the cursor.All() is taking almost double time. How to resolve this issue?